# Javascript Wait for Dynamic Input

Tags: javascript, random, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a variation of [a script to generate random numbers in multiple columns of a spreadsheet](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20587371%2Fscript-to-generate-random-numbers-in-multiple-cells&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGlD2CwIvHfHLbI4mrNKJbJVgjZ-g), as shared by Tim Cooper on stackoverflow, which works by selecting any range of contiguous cells and running the script from an onOpen menu.

The variation is implemented as a custom function in Google Sheets and uses values from an INPUT column (A) as maximum values for random numbers generated in the adjacent OUTPUT column (B), which in turn are used by the spreadsheet to derive the subsequent INPUT values. A simplified example:

> The custom function reads A1 and writes a random number between 0 and A1 (80) in B1. A2 is then calculated by adding 10 to B1, etc.

```
     |  A  |  B  |
  1  | 80  | 75  |
  2  | 85  | 63  |
  3  | 73  | 52  |
  4  | 62  | 40  |
  5  | 50  | 25  |
```

The problem is that the spreadsheet needs some time to fill in the next input value (in this case, A2), which will produce errors when it is too slow to supply the input for the custom function to calculate the random value in the next row.

As is, the custom function is a single block of code which identifies the active sheet and range of cells. It then loops through the number of rows, retrieving input values, determining the random values and writing them to the adjacent cells.

```
function generate_random_numbers()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  var counter = 0

  for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++)
  {
   counter = counter + 1
   if (counter != 3)
   {
    var maximum = range.getCell(y, 1).getValue()
    var random = (maximum != 0) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) + 1: 0
   }
    else
   {
    random = ""
    counter = 0
   }
   range.getCell(y, 2).setValue(random)
  }
}
```

I looked into splitting the function into a seperate part which retrieves the values, with an isNaN check to determine success and in case of failure setTimeout the function for 100. Unfortunately, Google Apps Script doesn't seem to support setTimeout.

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to get a spreadsheet and a script which uses dynamic values to work smoothly together.

Comment: I would only use `.getValue()` once to get the first value.  You stated that the next A column value is set by adding 10 to the last B column value.  So, the code has that value available to it.  You don't need to retrieve it from the sheet.  If you have formulas in column A, get rid of them, and just set the A column value from code.

Comment: @Sandy - the example is a simplification. The actual calculations are more complicated and involve other moving parts over multiple cells.

Comment: This might be a stupid, crazy idea, but if you could somehow run JavaScript from HTML, and use an AJAX request somehow, there are ways to wait until the response comes back.

Comment: By now, if have tried, without success, several custom function constructions which sleep for some time before retesting a cell to see if its value has changed. I'm beginning to suspect that custom functions do not have access to "live" spreadsheets, but that values are cached after they have been read once.

Comment: It seems that Google Apps Script's look-ahead caching was indeed the problem. The custom function works by using a SpreadsheetApp.flush() command in the do while loop, which refreshes the cache to reflect the latest values. Working on speeding up the custom function, and will supply the code as an answer.

Comment: Combining SpreadsheetApp.flush() and Utilities.sleep in a loop helps, but it is slow and doesn't prevent other cells getting stuck "Loading..." -- perhaps due to interaction of many slow numbers. In the end, I abbandoned the approach and moved all the calculations from the spreadsheet into the custom function. It took some learning, but it is much faster and never freezes. By storing the values in global arrays (per character and into rounds and values referenced by global variables instead of numbers) and isolating the calculations in their own functions, it is easy to manage and tinker with.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  Can you post an answer, at least showing some basic code?  That way people can quickly see that this isn't still an open ended issue.

Comment: Sandy, to my mind the matter of how to get Google Sheets and Google Apps Script custom functions to work together smoothly remains an open question. While I am no longer looking for an answer, I think any further suggestions or comments on the topic might be helpful to others exploring the issue. That said, having less experience with StackOverflow than you probably do, if you think this question is more likely to languish than receive further input I will defer to you and close it.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what level of importance Google would place on this, and what their proposal would be.  You could post this as an issue here:  [Apps Script Issues and Requests](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: If you're interested: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4425&thanks=4425&ts=1412263140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Google Apps Script's look-ahead caching, which limits custom functions to those values which were present in a spreadsheet at the time the custom function was invoked.

It is possible to use SpreadsheetApp.flush() to update the cache -- writing out the new values calculated by the custom function to the spreadsheet and reading in the resulting values from the spreadsheet into the cache -- but the approach is slow as it needs to be done repeatedly to keep the cache fresh and even then some cells in the spreadsheet may get stuck "Loading..."

In the end, I chose to move all the calculations from the spreadsheet into custom functions. It took some learning, but it is much faster and never freezes. By storing the values in global arrays (per character and into rounds and values referenced by easily named global constants instead of numbers) and isolating the calculations in their own functions, it is easy to manage and tinker with.

As the fundamental issue was never resolved, but rather side-stepped, [I posted the issue on Google's Apps Script Issues and Requests](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4425&thanks=4425&ts=1412263140), per a suggestion by Sandy.